# Critical error while starting Eclipse (neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64) for Java EE developer

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-neon

First of all, I tried to run eclipse **(eclipse-jee-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64)** normally. Each time, it showed a splash screen for few seconds and disappers. Then I check with terminal. Running in the terminal with command ./eclipse prints the error messages. I have attached the full terminal output below.

```
    nalin@nalin:/opt/eclipse-neon$ ./eclipse
    org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
    (Eclipse:5741): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
    Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1
```

**Any idea what's going on ?**